# Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up - Command duration or timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

All I am trying to achieve is an assertion, that text entered in the description field displays after the update button is hit, but I am getting an error that I  mentioned in the Title above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

FYI - page does refresh after user hits the update button, however, I don't notice any change in the url though!

My code:

```
//send text to the description text field    
WebElement description = driver.findElement(By.id(PvtConstants.UPDATE_KEYNAME_DESCRIPTION_FIELD));
description.sendKeys(keyname_description);

//verify the text (this is the assertion)
verifyDisplay(description.getAttribute("textContent") + "", By.id(PvtConstants.UPDATE_KEYNAME_DESCRIPTION_FIELD));
```

HTML:

```
<li>
<span>2.</span>
<label class="input_label" for="keyname_description">Description</label>
<textarea style="line-height:normal;" id="keyname_description" name="description" maxlength="256">this is my description text</textarea>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `description.getText()` instead of `description.getAttribute("textContent")` ?

Comment: At what point are you hitting update button? after sendkeys? This error happens when the DOM gets reloaded. try doing with driver.findElement again to achieve what u require...

Comment: @VivekSingh Thanks, again! It worked, however, here is what I had to do. As you may notice above that I have been calling description.get(). Since, the page was "kinda" refreshing, I was loosing "description". To beat that show-stopper, I created a new WebElement with the same xpath, and gave that element a call.

Comment: Not able to understand which one of you voted down my question, and for WHAT REASON?!?!?!?!?!  :(

Answer (score 1):

In case of text field or text area, you need to get values using the attribute value. `**description.getAttribute("value")**`. I guess this is throwing the error as it could not find the attribute *textContent*.

Comment: sorry, no luck. Same message again!

Comment: Can u show me the html code with button. Is it a submit button or a regualr button?

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript Executor to get the text from text area.Let me know if this code doesn't work for you.

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;

String description_text=(String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('keyname_description').innerHTML");
System.out.println(description_text);
```